# How to use both Python multiprocessing and asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.7, python-multiprocessing

```
import asyncio
import httpx
from datetime import datetime


async def request_test(url):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        r = await client.get(url, timeout=None, headers=None)
        return len(r.text)

async def main(rest_api_url_list ):
    futures = [asyncio.ensure_future(request_test(url)) for url in rest_api_url_list ]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*futures)
    print(results)
    print(len(results))


start = datetime.now()
rest_api_url_list = [~~~~~~~~~~~~~]    # 2000EA
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(rest_api_url_list ))
loop.close()
end = datetime.now()
```

Hi,
I have 2000 api adress.
And I need to call 2000 concurrently in one VM.
So, I used the asyncio library to modify the code as above.
But, This solution is not satisfactory.
How can I increase the effect of parallel processing?
I think I have to use multiprocessing and asyncio at the same time.

Comment: You fail to specify what you mean by "solution not satisfactory". Do you get exceptions? Is it too slow? There are things you could try before switching to multiprocessing - for example, don't create a new session (client) for each request. Create a session only once in `main()` and pass it to each `request_test()`.

Comment: Yes, It is too slow...and I don't understand "Create a session only once in main() and bla~"
Can I see Example code?

Comment: Move the line `async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client` into the `main` function. Pass `client` as the second argument to `request_test`, i.e. replace `request_test(url)` with `request_test(url, client)`. Finally, modify `request_test` to accept `client` as parameter. I also recommend that you read a good introduction to asyncio, such as [this one](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/).

Comment: This way required more than time

Comment: Maybe you are being limited on the server side, or the server is simply incapable to provide the throughput you would like to get. Did you try running `curl` or similar in parallel to measure the timings you get that way?